# How do I get the actual dimensions (i.e., sans-black bars) of a YouTube video using the JS iframe API?

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe, youtube

I need to know the *actual* width and height of a YouTube video embedded in my website. [Here's a crude illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxZek.png).

I've searched through the API docs and I haven't found a way to do this. I've noticed the `player` variable contains a method called `showVideoInfo()` which overlays *exactly the data I want* on the video player... but unfortunately since it is in the iframe I'm unable to access it from JavaScript.

Is there any way to do this without having a backend script that queries the JSON API? Because I'd *seriously* rather not have to do that.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? I mean, need to be only with iframe API?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using jQuery. I'm currently looking into using JSONP for this, actually, but it'd be nice if I didn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjeohpb0/)

As I understand, this is what you want? Ignore I'm writing, the dimensions, It's onlye to let you know actual dimensions

```
    var vidWd = $('.videoCont iframe').width();
    var vidHg = $('.videoCont iframe').height();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function getDimension() {
 var vidWd = $('.videoCont iframe').width();
  var vidHg = $('.videoCont iframe').height();
  
  $('.videoCont h1 p').remove();
  $('.videoCont h1 span').remove();
  $('.videoCont h1').append('<p>These are the dimensions:</p><span>' + vidWd + ' Widht - ' + vidHg + ' Height</span>');
}
$(document).ready(getDimension);
$(window).resize(getDimension);
});
```

```css
.videoCont{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
}
.videoCont iframe{
  width: 100%;
}
.videoCont h1 p{
  font-size: 14px;
}
.videoCont h1 span{
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="videoCont">
  <h1>This is your video:</h1>
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Aoobcc3DyUs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
```